# NoClassDefFoundError when calling "write" method in poi

Tags: java, apache-poi, noclassdeffounderror

My code looks like this:

```
fileoutput = new FileOutputStream(productSheetFilePath);
m_psWorkBook.write(fileoutput);
```

Where **m_psWorkBook** is of type **XSSFWorkbook**, when calling the "write" method a NoClassDefFoundError exeption is throws, does anybody ever had that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use ooxml-schemas-1.0 .jar instead of this one poi-ooxml-schemas-3.6.jar